# jQuery onHover add class on another div

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, onhover

I have something like this !

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="main-div">
    <img src=""/>
    <div class="text">bla bla</div>
    <a class="button-a"></a>
    <a class="button-b"></a>
</div>
<div class="main-div">
    <img src=""/>
    <div class="text">bla bla</div>
    <a class="button-a"></a>
    <a class="button-b"></a>
</div>
<div class="main-div">
    <img src=""/>
    <div class="text">bla bla</div>
    <a class="button-a"></a>
    <a class="button-b"></a>
</div>
```

What i want to do is that onHover button-a or button-b, toggleClass to div#text, but only to the div#text inside main-div, not all over where div#text is! Thank you,

Comment: Use this `$('.button-a, .button-b').hover(function () { $(this).closest('.main-div').find('.text').toggleClass('active') })`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mouseenter` or `mouseleave` event on `.button-a, .button-b` selector.

```js
$(".button-a, .button-b").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).siblings("div").toggleClass("text");
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).siblings("div").toggleClass("text");
    }
});
```

```css
div.text {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main-div">
    <img src="" />
    <div class="text">bla bla</div>
    <a class="button-a">Link 1</a>
    <a class="button-b">Link 2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="main-div">
    <img src="" />
    <div class="text">bla bla</div>
    <a class="button-a">Link 1</a>
    <a class="button-b">Link 2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="main-div">
    <img src="" />
    <div class="text">bla bla</div>
    <a class="button-a">Link 1</a>
    <a class="button-b">Link 2</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').hover(function(){
    $(this).siblings('div').toggleClass('text');
})
```